# Pointwise convergence of a series of functions using the ratio test.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am asked to calculate the pointwise convergence of the series of functions

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{n!}}x^ne^{-nx^2}$$

Since it is a series of positive terms, I apply the ratio test and after simplifying $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ I got to $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x\sqrt{2}((1+1/n)^n(1+1/n))^{1/2}}{e^{x^2}}$$

As a hint, I was told that I should use $$(1+1/n)^n\geq\frac{e}{1+1/n}$$ For all $n\geq 1$

Therefore the initial series will converge if $$1>\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq \frac{x\sqrt{2e}}{e^{x^2}}$$

How do I finish the problem? If I had $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{x\sqrt{2e}}{e^{x^2}}$ I would say it converges for all $x$ such that $e^{x^2}<x\sqrt{2e}$.

Comment: Should the last inequality be $e^{x^2}>x\sqrt{2e}$?

Comment: Also, you need to take absolute values in the ratio test, so you should have $|x|\sqrt{2e}$

Comment: I don't see how you got $\sqrt2$ in the ratio.  Should that be $(2n)^{(n+1)/2}$ instead of $2n^{(n+1)/2}$ in the summand?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out, edited.

Comment: Hmm, that breaks my easy proof below for $x$ sufficiently close to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By ratio test we obtain

$$\left|\frac{[2(n+1)]^{\frac{n+2}{2}}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{[2n]^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\frac{x^{n+1}e^{-(n+1)x^2}}{x^ne^{-nx^2}}\right|=\sqrt 2|x|e^{-x^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{n+1}2\to \sqrt {2e}|x|e^{-x^2}\le 1$$

for $\sqrt {2e}|x|e^{-x^2}=1 \implies |x|e^{-x^2}=\frac1{\sqrt{2e}} $ we have

$$\left|\frac{2n^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{n!}}x^ne^{-nx^2}\right|=\frac{(2n)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac1{(2e)^\frac n2}\sim \frac{(2n)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi n}n^\frac n 2}\frac{e^\frac n 2}{(2e)^\frac n2}=\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi n}} \to \infty$$

Therefore the given series converges for any $x\in \mathbb R$ such that  $\sqrt {2e}|x|e^{-x^2}<1$.

Comment: Revisiting your answer, this would mean that for $x=0$, the series converge, so $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{n!}}$ should converge, but it doesn't, right?

Comment: @JohnKeeper For $x=0$ the series becomes $\sum 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a supplement to user's excellent answer, showing how the hint was supposed to be applied.  As shown in that answer, the ratio $$\sqrt 2|x|e^{-x^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{(n+1)/2}\to r,$$ where $r<1$ unless $\sqrt 2|x|e^{-x^2}=1$.  In that case, the ratio is $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{(n+1)/2}>\sqrt{e\over1+1/n}\to\sqrt e>1,$$ by the hint.

Comment: However, when you say "means that the given series converges if $e^{x^2}>|x|\sqrt{2e}$" this is the same as $1>\frac{|x|\sqrt{2e}}{e^{x^2}}$. Wouldn't it be possible that, since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq \frac{x\sqrt{2e}}{e^{x^2}}$, $\frac{x\sqrt{2e}}{e^{x^2}}<1$ but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$? And therefore even if $\frac{x\sqrt{2e}}{e^{x^2}}<1$ the initial series wouldn't converge, since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$.

Comment: @JohnKeeper You're right.  I need to rethink this.

Comment: John Keeper's comment applies to a previous version of this answer, since deleted.